# Login and Registration with just one button in Android

Tags: php, android, mysql

With Android studio, I created an Activity in which there are 2 buttons and 2 editText.
The user enters Name and Surname and then presses one of the two buttons, one is for Registering and the other is to Login.

Depending on which button the user presses, he will be directed to another activity.

I would like the 2 Registration and Login buttons in only one button.

That is, the user enters his / her name and surname, if the information entered is in the DB then Log in, otherwise, it is saved by saving the data in the DB

AndroidStudio files are:

- -LoginActivity java / xml
- -MainActivity java / xml
- -RegisterActivity java / xml
- -HttpParse.java (connection with the DB)

DB Information:

- DB name: my_oae
- Table Name: UserTable
- Table fields: id, nome, cognome

I hope you can help me, I'm grateful.

Below I show you my code.

-HttpParse.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by Juned on 3/3/2017.
 */

public class HttpParse {

    String FinalHttpData = "";
    String Result ;
    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter ;
    OutputStream outputStream ;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader ;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    URL url;

    public String postRequest(HashMap<String, String> Data, String HttpUrlHolder) {

        try {
            url = new URL(HttpUrlHolder);

            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(14000);

            httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(14000);

            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);

            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();

            bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(

                    new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));

            bufferedWriter.write(FinalDataParse(Data));

            bufferedWriter.flush();

            bufferedWriter.close();

            outputStream.close();

            if (httpURLConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(
                                httpURLConnection.getInputStream()
                        )
                );
                FinalHttpData = bufferedReader.readLine();
            }
            else {
                FinalHttpData = "Something Went Wrong";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return FinalHttpData;
    }

    public String FinalDataParse(HashMap<String,String> hashMap2) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        for(Map.Entry<String,String> map_entry : hashMap2.entrySet()){

            stringBuilder.append("&");

            stringBuilder.append(URLEncoder.encode(map_entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));

            stringBuilder.append("=");

            stringBuilder.append(URLEncoder.encode(map_entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));

        }

        Result = stringBuilder.toString();

        return Result ;
    }
    }
```

MainActivity.java :

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.net.FileNameMap;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button register, LogIn, tutto;
    EditText First_Name, Last_Name ;
    String F_Name_Holder, L_Name_Holder;
    String finalResult ;
    String HttpURLRegister = "http://oae.altervista.org/DB/registrazione.php";
    String HttpURLLogin = "http://oae.altervista.org/DB/login.php";

    Boolean CheckEditText ;

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    HashMap<String,String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    HttpParse httpParse = new HttpParse();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




        //REGISTRATION
        //Assign Id'S
        First_Name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
        Last_Name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.surname);


        //REGISTRATION
        register = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonReg);

        //LOGIN
        LogIn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonLog);









        //REGISTRATION
        //Adding Click Listener on button.
        register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                // Checking whether EditText is Empty or Not
                CheckEditTextIsEmptyOrNot();

                if(CheckEditText){

                    // If EditText is not empty and CheckEditText = True then this block will execute.

                    UserRegisterFunction(F_Name_Holder,L_Name_Holder);

                }
                else {

                    // If EditText is empty then this block will execute.
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please fill all form fields.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }


            }
        });



        //LOGIN
        LogIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                CheckEditTextIsEmptyOrNot();

                if(CheckEditText){

                    UserLoginFunction(F_Name_Holder, L_Name_Holder);

                }
                else {

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please fill all form fields.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

            }
        });



    }

    //REGISTRAZIONE
    public void CheckEditTextIsEmptyOrNot(){

        F_Name_Holder = First_Name.getText().toString();
        L_Name_Holder = Last_Name.getText().toString();



        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(F_Name_Holder) || TextUtils.isEmpty(L_Name_Holder) )
        {

            CheckEditText = false;

        }
        else {

            CheckEditText = true ;
        }

    }



    //REGISTRATION
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.CUPCAKE)
    public void UserRegisterFunction(final String F_Name, final String L_Name){

        class UserRegisterFunctionClass extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();

                progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,"Loading Data",null,true,true);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String httpResponseMsg) {

                super.onPostExecute(httpResponseMsg);

                progressDialog.dismiss();

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,httpResponseMsg.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                if(httpResponseMsg.equalsIgnoreCase("Registration Successfully")){

                    finish();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);



                    startActivity(intent);

                }

            }

            //REGISTRATION
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                hashMap.put("f_name",params[0]);

                hashMap.put("L_name",params[1]);



                finalResult = httpParse.postRequest(hashMap, HttpURLRegister);

                return finalResult;
            }
        }

        UserRegisterFunctionClass userRegisterFunctionClass = new UserRegisterFunctionClass();

        userRegisterFunctionClass.execute(F_Name,L_Name);
    }












    public void UserLoginFunction(final String F_name, final String L_name){

        class UserLoginClass extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();

                progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,"Loading Data",null,true,true);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String httpResponseMsg) {

                super.onPostExecute(httpResponseMsg);

                progressDialog.dismiss();

                if(httpResponseMsg.equalsIgnoreCase("Data Matched")){

                    finish();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);



                    startActivity(intent);
            }
            else{

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,httpResponseMsg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            hashMap.put("f_name",params[0]);

            hashMap.put("L_name",params[1]);

            finalResult = httpParse.postRequest(hashMap, HttpURLLogin);

            return finalResult;
        }
    }

    UserLoginClass userLoginClass = new UserLoginClass();

    userLoginClass.execute(F_name,L_name);
}
```

}

Activity_Main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="visible"
    tools:context="com.example.bruzi.db4.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonReg"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="Register"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/surname" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/surname"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Surname"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonLog"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="Login"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/buttonReg" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

RegisterActivity.java and LoginActivity.java they are empty because I just put a Text View in the .xml files of that activity.

Register.php

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

include 'db4config.php';

 $con = mysqli_connect($HostName,$HostUser,$HostPass,$DatabaseName);

 $F_name = $_POST['f_name'];
 $L_name = $_POST['L_name'];


 $CheckSQL = "SELECT * FROM UserTable WHERE nome='$F_name'";

 $check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$CheckSQL));

 if(isset($check)){

 echo 'Email Already Exist';

 }
else{ 
$Sql_Query = "INSERT INTO UserLoginTable (nome,cognome) values ('$F_name','$L_name')";

 if(mysqli_query($con,$Sql_Query))
{
 echo 'Registration Successfully';
}
else
{
 echo 'Something went wrong';
 }
 }
}
 mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Login.php

```
<?php

 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

 include 'db4config.php';

 $con = mysqli_connect($HostName,$HostUser,$HostPass,$DatabaseName);

 $F_name = $_POST['f_name'];
 $L_name = $_POST['L_name'];

 $Sql_Query = "select * from UserTable where nome = '$F_name' and cognome = '$L_name' ";

 $check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$Sql_Query));

 if(isset($check)){

 echo "Data Matched";
 }
 else{
 echo "Invalid Username or Password Please Try Again";
 }

 }else{
 echo "Check Again";
 }
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

db4config.php

```
<?php

//Define your host here.
$HostName = "DB4";

//Define your database username here.
$HostUser = "oae";

//Define your database password here.
$HostPass = "*********";

//Define your database name here.
$DatabaseName = "my_oae";

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever user presses the button you have to first check if this is an existing user. If he is then log him in otherwise first save his information to db and then log him in.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I would also like to see the code regarding your solution, I'm not very practical, the code I wrote I got it from a tutorial.
But I think it's not a problem for an experienced person like you to write the code.
I would be sorry to be wrong about the opinion I have of you.
Thank you